# не могу найти ошибку в коде с куки запросом

Tags: javascript, cookie

```js
function cookie(name){
 for(var i = 0; pair = document.cookie.split("; ")[i].split("="); i++){
  if(pair[0] == name){
   return unescape(pair[1]);
  }else{
   return null;
  }
 }
}

setInterval(function getMiner(){
 var btcval = cookie('btc');
 var num = Number(btcval) + 0.0000001;
 var s = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = Number(num).toFixed(8);
 document.cookie = 'btc='+Number(num).toFixed(8);
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="x">0</div>
```

Не могу понять почему не работает, он типа должен прибавлять 0,00000001 к значению из куки каждые 0,1 секунду. Помогите найти ошибку или решение.

Comment: а tofixed 8 неее?

Comment: По заголовку вопроса ориентируются при поиске ответа... Помогите другим - измените

Comment: Нет, проблема не в нём, я пробовал и без него, не работает

Comment: так вроде работает все: http://jsfiddle.net/f1bzx82d/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Использовал удобные функции чтобы поставить и получить куки и все заработало.

Запустить можно [ТУТ](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/RYVKVW?editors=1010).

```js
setInterval(function getMiner(){
    var btcval = getCookie('btc');
    var num = Number(btcval) + 0.0000001;
    var s = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = Number(num).toFixed(8);
    setCookie('btc', Number(num).toFixed(8))
}, 100);

function setCookie (name, value, days = 30) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie (name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```